# WP components no style

Tags: admin-menu, admin-css

I'm trying to build a plugin menu using wordpress components but it appears all the styles are missing. For ex. the button isn't colored the primary(Blue) in the following sandbox..

https://codesandbox.io/s/my-account-modal-lrj1s?file=/src/App.tsx

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I had to just import the package style sheet located at
`node_modules/@wordpress/components/build-style/style.css`